# Show multi-layered/ multi-leveled item in tabular view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a **list of multi-layered or multi-layered item in tree view as below.**
[image]

But i **have  to show these multi-layered or multi-layered items in tabular view with it's level** as below[image]

as per my requirement i used the code:

```
 public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }        
    public List<Comment> Children { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    List<Comment> categories = new List<Comment>()
        {
            new Comment () { Id = 1, Text = "Category B", ParentId = 0},
            new Comment() { Id = 2, Text = "Child B", ParentId = 1 },
            new Comment() { Id = 3, Text = "Category A", ParentId = 0 },
            new Comment() { Id = 4, Text = "Child A", ParentId = 3 },
            new Comment() { Id = 5, Text = "Grand Child", ParentId = 4 }
        };

        List<Comment> hierarchy = new List<Comment>();
        hierarchy = categories
                        .Where(c => c.ParentId == 0)
                        .Select(c => new Comment() { 
                              Id = c.Id, 
                              Text = c.Text, 
                              ParentId = c.ParentId, 
                              Children = GetChildren(categories, c.Id) })
                        .ToList();

        HieararchyWalk(hierarchy);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<Comment> GetChildren(List<Comment> comments, int parentId)
    {
        return comments
                .Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId)
                .Select(c => new Comment { 
                    Id = c.Id, 
                    Text = c.Text, 
                    ParentId = c.ParentId, 
                    Children = GetChildren(comments, c.Id) })
                .ToList();
    }

    public static void HieararchyWalk(List<Comment> hierarchy)
    {
        if (hierarchy != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in hierarchy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Id, item.Text));
                HieararchyWalk(item.Children);
            }
        }
    }
```

it's giving me the data in required format.
**How can i render the data in tabular view with it's level** as shown in second picture above (lavel of item is not fixed)